# Save query in PHP variables

Tags: php, postgresql

I have doubt  to save data from a query in Postgresql in PHP variables

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=NameBd', 'postgres',  '12345'); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select 
c.telefono_movil,
m.mensaje,
(Select to_char(fecha_mensaje_detalle,'mm-dd')) as fecha

from mensaje_detalle md
inner join cliente c on (c.codigo_cliente=md.codigo_cliente)
inner join mensaje m on (m.codigo_mensaje=md.codigo_mensaje)"); 

$stmt->execute(); 
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 var_dump($row['telefono_movil']);
 var_dump($row['mensaje']);
 var_dump($row['fecha']);
}
?>
```

I would like to save the three objects that I extract from my database into variables.

```
   var_dump($row['telefono_movil']);
   var_dump($row['mensaje']);
   var_dump($row['fecha']);
```

Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: You can! `$my_fecha = $row['fecha'];`

Comment: Use php's extract function

Comment: @SohailAhmed never use `extract`

Comment: why not to use extract. it will convert array names to variables

Comment: For example, suppose someone modifies the post request to include `$_POST["_SESSION[userid]"] = 1`, this would write to your session that your userid is 1. It isn't safe. - Have a play with this: https://eval.in/686722

Comment: @ʰᵈ `EXTR_SKIP`, but yeah in general I agree

Comment: inside your loop `$tel = $row['telefono_movil'];
 $mensaje = $row['mensaje'];
 $fecha = $row['fecha'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r( json_encode( $stmt->fetchAll() ) );
```

And then you can store the value you want with the key.